# Validate dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, validation, uniform

I have a registration form which uses one of jquery plugin for client side validation. I can validate textboxes and other controls but I have a problem with dropdownlist.
I have a field on registration page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSector" runat="server" class="validateCallback my_code_callback"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Those dropdown list outputs that

```
<select name="ddlSector" class="validateCallback my_code_callback">
   <option value="244">--Choose--</option>
   <option value="27">Hotel</option>
   <option value="28">Motel</option>
   <option value="29">Cottage</option>
</select>
```

and I have such implementation on master template

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/uni-form-validation.jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('form.uniForm').uniform({
                prevent_submit: true
            });              
          });  
          window.my_code_callback = function (field, caption) {
          if (field.val() === '244') {
              return false;
            }
          }    
    </script>
```

in jquery file which does validation has such example

```
 /**
         * Callback validator
         *
         * Lets you define your own validators. Usage:
         *
         * <input name="myinput" class="validateCallback my_callback" />
         *
         * This will result in UniForm searching for window.my_callback funciton and
         * executing it with field and caption arguments. Sample implementation:
         *
         * window.my_callback = function (field, caption) {
         *   if (field.val() === '34') {
         *     return true;
         *   } else {
         *     return caption + ' value should be "34"';
         *   }
         * }
         *
         * @param jQuery field
         * @param caption
         */
        validateCallback : function (field, caption) {
            var classes = field.attr('class').split(' '),
                callback_function = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
                if (classes[i] === 'validateCallback') {
                    if (classes[i + 1] != 'undefined') {
                        callback_function = classes[i + 1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (window[callback_function] != 'undefined' && (typeof window[callback_function] === 'function')) {
                return window[callback_function](field, caption);
            }

            return i18n('callback', caption, callback_function);
        }

    };
```

How could I change the code so if visitor leaves the option --Choose--, it should display the error like other controls?

Answer (score 0):

`if($('#ddlSector').selectedIndex == 0)` might work?

or maybe:

```
if($("#ddlSector").attr("selectedIndex") == 0)
```

Comment: I changed if (field.val() === '244') line with your suggestion but both of the suggestion did not work out.

Comment: It is not such a thing I made diffucult. I just followed and tried what it was told in documentation. Have any idea still?